# Any alternate of REGEXP_LIKE as it causing performance issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, query-optimization

We have one sql which is performing bad.I have fixed the execution plan but REGEXP_LIKE causing high buffer gets and also contribute in runtime.Any alternate which i can use in my sql.The problematc is
AND REGEXP_LIKE (xx3la.assembly_type, '^I..*')

```
/* Formatted on 1/6/2023 2:07:28 PM (QP5 v5.318) */
SELECT 1
  FROM apps.oe_order_lines_all  ola
       JOIN APPS.OE_order_headers_all oh
           ON oh.Header_Id = ola.header_id AND oh.org_id = ola.org_id
       JOIN inv.mtl_parameters org
           ON ola.ship_from_org_id = org.ORGANIZATION_ID
       INNER JOIN ont.oe_transaction_types_tl tt
           ON     tt.transaction_type_id = oh.order_type_id
              AND tt.language = 'US'
              AND LPAD (UPPER (tt.name), 4) NOT IN ('TRIA',
                                                    'WARR',
                                                    'REPA',
                                                    'DUMM',
                                                    'DEMO',
                                                    'GOOD',
                                                    'INTE',
                                                    'CRED',
                                                    'EVAL',
                                                    'INVO')      --- ('STAND')
       JOIN apps.mtl_system_items_b msib
           ON     ola.Ordered_item_Id = msib.inventory_item_id
              AND msib.ORGANIZATION_ID = org.ORGANIZATION_ID
       INNER JOIN xxom.xxom_3lp_sym_ora_order_hdr xx3ha
           ON xx3ha.header_id = oh.header_id
       INNER JOIN xxom.xxom_3lp_sym_ora_order_lines xx3la
           ON xx3la.header_id = ola.header_id AND xx3la.line_id = ola.line_id
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT msib.Inventory_item_id,
               mcb.segment1 ProductionLine,
               msib.ORGANIZATION_ID,
               msib.item_type,
               msib.Fixed_LEAD_Time
          FROM apps.mtl_system_items_b  msib
               JOIN inv.mtl_parameters org
                   ON msib.ORGANIZATION_ID = org.ORGANIZATION_ID
               JOIN apps.MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES ic
                   ON     ic.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = msib.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                      AND msib.organization_id = ic.ORGANIZATION_ID
               JOIN apps.mtl_categories_b mcb
                   ON mcb.CATEGORY_ID = ic.CATEGORY_ID
         WHERE mcb.ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y' AND ic.CATEGORY_SET_ID = 1100009407) im
           ON     ola.Ordered_item_Id = im.inventory_item_id
              AND org.organization_id = im.organization_id
       LEFT JOIN (  SELECT Header_Id,
                           Line_Id,
                           WIP_ORDER_NUMBER,
                           MAX (PRODUCT_LINE) PRODUCT_LINE
                      FROM XXRMT.XXURD_SO_UNIT
                  GROUP BY Header_Id, Line_Id, WIP_ORDER_NUMBER) u
           ON u.Header_Id = oh.Header_Id AND u.Line_Id = ola.Line_Id
       LEFT JOIN wip.wip_discrete_jobs wdj
           ON     wdj.source_line_id = ola.line_id
              AND wdj.status_type IN (1,
                                      2,
                                      3,
                                      4,
                                      5,
                                      12)
       LEFT JOIN wip.wip_entities we ON we.wip_entity_id = wdj.wip_entity_id
       LEFT JOIN xxrmt.xxont_som_scheduler adm
           ON adm.subscriber_id = xx3la.order_admin
       LEFT JOIN apps.oe_order_lines_all ol2
           ON     ol2.ato_line_id = ola.line_id
              AND ol2.item_type_code IN ('CONFIG')
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT mso.source_organization_code,
               mso.vendor_name,
               mso.vendor_site,
               msa.sourcing_rule_name,
               DECODE (mso.source_type,
                       1, 'TRANSFER',
                       2, 'MAKE',
                       3, 'BUY')
                   SourceType,
               msa.inventory_item_id,
               msa.organization_id
          FROM apps.mrp_sr_assignments_v  msa
               --join inv.mtl_parameters    org  on msa.organization_id = org.organization_id
               INNER JOIN apps.mrp_sourcing_rules msr
                   ON msr.sourcing_rule_id = msa.sourcing_rule_id
               INNER JOIN apps.mrp_sr_receipt_org_v msro
                   ON msr.sourcing_rule_id = msro.sourcing_rule_id
               INNER JOIN apps.mrp_sr_source_org_v mso
                   ON mso.sr_receipt_id = msro.sr_receipt_id AND mso.RANK = 1
         WHERE     msa.assignment_set_id = 561
               AND (msro.disable_date IS NULL OR disable_date >= SYSDATE))
       srd
           ON     srd.inventory_item_id = ol2.inventory_item_id
              AND srd.organization_id = ola.ship_from_org_id
 WHERE     org.organization_code IN ('DRM')
       AND ola.Flow_Status_Code <> 'CANCELLED'
       AND NVL (oh.Cancelled_flag, 'N') = 'N'
       AND oh.Flow_Status_Code <> 'CANCELLED'
       AND ola.booked_flag = 'Y'
       AND oh.booked_date IS NOT NULL
       AND TRUNC (oh.booked_date) >= TO_DATE ('2022-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
       AND msib.item_type NOT IN ('P',
                                  'B/R',
                                  'OP',
                                  'SVC',
                                  'OP',
                                  'EMR_PURCH')
       AND (   ola.item_type_code IN ('CONFIG', 'MODEL')
            OR (    ola.item_type_code IN ('CLASS')
                AND REGEXP_LIKE (xx3la.assembly_type, '^I..*'))
            OR (    ola.item_type_code IN ('CLASS')
                AND u.PRODUCT_LINE IS NOT NULL
                AND xx3la.model_string IS NOT NULL
                AND msib.segment1 NOT IN ('R-CAP1199', 'R-38-315'))
            OR (    ola.item_type_code = 'STANDARD'
                AND xx3la.assembly_type IS NULL))
```

Somehow fixed the BG issue but still REGEXP_LIKE an issue

Answer (score 5):

Your current regex assertion:

```sql
REGEXP_LIKE(xx3la.assembly_type, '^I..*')
```

can be written using an ordinary `LIKE`:

```sql
xx3la.assembly_type LIKE 'I_%'
```

Note that the above `LIKE` version should be able to use an index on `assembly_type`.  That being said, I doubt that the `REGEXP_LIKE` call be the only major performance bottleneck existing in a query of this size and complexity.  You should run `EXPLAIN` on your query to view the execution plan.

Comment: It is also not picking correct plan

Comment: What is the "correct plan"? Regardless, this answer seems to address the question that was originally asked. Plan selection is a different question

Comment: @Jack Shadow: I agree with user20042973. Tim has properly answered your question and even hinted you look at the execution plan. You should accept this answer hence. Then try to figure out why Oracle accesses the data differently from what you expect. Are you missing an important index? Maybe you can boil down the problem to a part of the whole query. If you need more help, ask a new question.

Comment: Actually there is no way anybody can provide you with assistance on the performance of your query. It would require someone inside your organization who can examine the wait data to determine what's wrong. Don't assume it's REGEXP. Just because adding it makes things go south doesn't mean it's at fault... any change at all can result in a significant change in execution plan. Usually bad performance is due to cardinality misestimates that drive suboptimal join methods or join order. I'm afraid that it's not possible for meaningful assistance with that to come from a forum like this.